# DICOM image registration using ITK

Tags: vtk, dicom, point-clouds, itk

I'm working on a project (VS2012 and C#) that includes image registration. I basically need to extract the points cloud from a stack of DICOM images in a directory. I've researched ActiViz, VTK, ITK etc and I can't find any example on how to do this.

Has someone been able to obtain a cloud of points using any of these libraries above? if so, can you post the code used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question how exactly is represented your point cloud in the DICOM image stack.

I suppose the points are pixels in the slices that have a particular color. In this case, the ITK Software Guide has a fully documented example about how to extract a surface from a 3D DICOM image: It is chapter "6.11 Extracting Surfaces" ([link to the book](http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf)).

This example uses an ITK filter that performs a thresholding step to isolate your points and then performs the surface extraction.

It is not exactly what you are asking for though: this example outputs a mesh instead of a set of points. However, in ITK a mesh *is a kind* of point set (class `vtkMesh` derives from `vtkPointset`) so you can get your cloud of points from there.

See also chapters "4.2 PointSet" and "4.3 Mesh" in the same book.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps. I basically need to do a skin contour and extract the points to use them later on to calibrate with other points I got using a NDI tracker. The points are actually a list of triangles, each triangle with 3 points (x, y and z)..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in ANALYZE software and extract the cloud points. 
https://analyzedirect.com/analyze-registration/

Let me know if you have questions about how to do it.